# Using AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, shadow-copy

I've got a ton of DLLs used by my website.  Most of them never change, but I frequently change 1 of them.

Every time I do the site is down for about 5 minutes while IIS restarts.  I'd like to reduce this.

I've read about shadow copying being slow when you have a lot of DLL files so I'd like to disable it in most cases, but I do want to use it on my frequently modified DLL so I can change that without having to stop IIS.

The documentation on shadow copying seems to presume you are setting it up before the AppDomain is created, but IIS handles the creation of the AppDomain so I don't know how to use the AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories property to tell it not to do any shadow copying in the main /bin folder and only shadow copy things in the /bin/changesFrequently folder.  Can I set this in web.config somehow?  Is there a way to run c# code in IIS before the shadowcopy process starts?